# Import audio files in python for analysis e.g Signal Analysis

Tags: python, git, ipython, signal-processing, jupyter

```
I am trying to import a .wav file to perform Signal analysis on it. I have used all the Ipython,wave libraries that i am meant to import but its still showing me error.Some of the libraries were gotten from a book downloaded from git hub repository(https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkDSP). Can anyone one show me what is wrong with the code?

(This is after importing all necessary libraries in the book and in python)
```

---

Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 wave= thinkdsp.read_wave('365515__noedell__noedell-shady-scheme-01.wav')

C:\Users\Ademola\Desktop\500 Level\DSP\DSP_Python\ThinkDSP-master\ThinkDSP-master\code\thinkdsp.py in read_wave(filename)
     99     returns: Wave
    100     """
--> 101     fp = open_wave(filename, 'r')
    102 
    103     nchannels = fp.getnchannels()

C:\Users\Ademola\Anaconda3\lib\wave.py in open(f, mode)
    497             mode = 'rb'
    498     if mode in ('r', 'rb'):
--> 499         return Wave_read(f)
    500     elif mode in ('w', 'wb'):
    501         return Wave_write(f)
    C:\Users\Ademola\Anaconda3\lib\wave.py in **init**(self, f)
        161         # else, assume it is an open file object already
        162         try:
    --> 163             self.initfp(f)
        164         except:
        165             if self._i_opened_the_file:

```
C:\Users\Ademola\Anaconda3\lib\wave.py in initfp(self, file)
    141             chunkname = chunk.getname()
    142             if chunkname == b'fmt ':
--> 143                 self._read_fmt_chunk(chunk)
    144                 self._fmt_chunk_read = 1
    145             elif chunkname == b'data':
C:\Users\Ademola\Anaconda3\lib\wave.py in _read_fmt_chunk(self, chunk)
    258             self._sampwidth = (sampwidth + 7) // 8
    259         else:
--> 260             raise Error('unknown format: %r' % (wFormatTag,))
    261         self._framesize = self._nchannels * self._sampwidth
    262         self._comptype = 'NONE'

Error: unknown format: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code its hard to answer your question...you can read wav files with the wav module that comes standard in python.  Basic syntax below:

```
import wave

wav = wave.open('wavFile.wav', 'r')
```

here is the documentation:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I trried the code but its still showing me file not found error and I have copied the file into the directory am working on.This is the error code below         fileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-3f79b3865913> in <module>()
----> 1 wav = wave.open('365515__noedell__noedell-shady-scheme-01', 'r')

C:\Users\Ademola\Anaconda3\lib\wave.py in open(f, mode)
    497             mode = 'rb'
    498     if mode in ('r', 'rb'):
--> 499         return Wave_read(f)
    500     elif mode in ('w', 'wb'):
    501         return Wave_write(f)

Comment: what is `365515__noedell__noedell-shady-scheme-01`?  You should have the .wav file where you have this.  Could you update your question and paste your code in there?